# Mi API sólo me permite registrar un usuario - NodeJS / MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy trabajando con NodeJS y MongoDB para crear una API que me ayude a registrar usuarios y al momento del registro se genere un accessToken para que se mantenga la sesión del usuario. Encontré código para lograrlo y me funcionó de maravilla, pero me tomé un par de semanas de descanso y ahora que vuelvo a retomar el proyecto lo que ocurre es que la aplicación sólo me deja registrar a una persona, si intento registrar otra me genera un error

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: carlosescobar.usuarios index: username_1 dup key: { : null }

No se si se deba a una actualización, en consola cuando inicio el servidor me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> (node:10868) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Les dejo el código del modelo de la BD:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

var UsuariosSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String, //Tipo de dato
    required: true, //El campo es obligatorio
    trim: true //Los espacios serán eliminados
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true //El elemento debe ser unico y no repetirse
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
}, {
    timestamps: true //Guardar la fecha de creación y de actualización
  });
  
module.exports = UsuariosSchema;
```

Código del DAO:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const usuariosSchema = require('../models/usuarios');

usuariosSchema.statics = {
  create: function (data, cb) {
    const user = new this(data);
    user.save(cb);
  },
  login: function (query, cb) {
    this.find(query, cb);
  }
}

const usuariosModel = mongoose.model('Usuarios', usuariosSchema);
module.exports = usuariosModel;
```

Código del Controller:

```js
'use strict'

var Usuarios = require('../dao/usuarios');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey123456';


var controller = {

    // METODO PARA REGISTRAR USUARIO
    RegistroUsuarios: function(req, res, next) {
      
      const newUser = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password)
      }
    
      Usuarios.create(newUser, (err, user) => {
        console.log(err);
        if(err && err.code === 11000){
          return res.status(409).send('El email ya esxiste');
        }

        if(err){
          return res.status(500).send('Error del servidor');
        }

        const expiresIn = 24 * 60 * 60;
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user.id },
          
          SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: expiresIn
        
        });

        const dataUser = {

          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          accessToken: accessToken,
          expiresIn: expiresIn

        }

        // response 
        res.send({ dataUser });

      });
    }
```

Código de las Routers:

```js
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var UsuariosController = require('../controllers/usuarios');
var router = express.Router();


//Rutas POST
router.post('/register', UsuariosController.RegistroUsuarios);
router.post('/login', UsuariosController.loginUser);


//Rutas GET

router.get('/users', UsuariosController.getUsers);


module.exports = router;
```

> **Nota:** También quiero mencionar que si borro el usuario que tengo en la BD e intento más registros, me registra sólo un nuevo usuario,
>   cuando intento registrar otro no me lo permite y me sale el error
>   **E11000**.

Comment: ¿Has probado registrar con otro correo?

Comment: Sí, el método de registrar está pensado para eso, un registro donde el correo sea único.

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado, por alguna razón la tabla (collection) estaba generando este problema, lo que hice fue eliminarla y volver a crearla.

Comment: En la parte inferior de este página hay una caja de texto cuyo título es "Tu Respuesta", agrega toda la información detallada de lo que realizaste, serás el héroe de más usuarios con el mismo problema o similar situación :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es sencilla, borrar la colección (tabla) y volver a crearla. Mi problema es que realicé cambios en el código para probar algo diferente, después de hacer las pruebas volví a agregar el mismo código que tenia en un principio esto generó un conflicto en la colección.